# Laravel 5.2 Split String First Name Last Name

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a string passed from a form which is full name.

in my database I store first name and last name.. I've split the string using the following:

```
$name = explode(" ", $request->name);
$lastname = array_pop($name);
$firstname = implode(" ", $name);
```

this works great, however, if the user doesn't enter a surname in the field then the above doesn't work as the lastname becomes the first.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Force the user to enter a `first_name` and `last_name`, and store them as such. When you want to return a `full_name`, just return `$first_name." ".$last_name`. Concatenation is a better solution than relying on the user supplying correct information, or assuming that names won't contain spaces.

Comment: I do agree with @TimLewis. However, in some cases like a signup process, you want to cook the amount of fields a user need to fill out down to an absolute minimum. In that case, IMO it's ok to just "guess" which part is the first and last name, but storing them separately and giving the user an opportunity to edit them separately later on if they wish.

Comment: @Dencker Fair point on the subject of keeping it simple. For like 90% of cases, names won't have a space in them, and it's ok to assume that, but it's still good to be aware of and try to account for the edge cases, such as someone's first name being something like "Mary Ann".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what I've used for splitting names:

```
$splitName = explode(' ', $name, 2); // Restricts it to only 2 values, for names like Billy Bob Jones

$first_name = $splitName[0];
$last_name = !empty($splitName[1]) ? $splitName[1] : ''; // If last name doesn't exist, make it empty
```

Comment: This doesn't consider the middle name case

Comment: No, as the comments say, only 2 values, since the request was for first and last. It's not exact, so names like Mary Jane Watson will become "Mary" "Jane Watson". But it's really hard to predict name splits with just code.

Answer (score 6):

I usually do this, which is very similar to what you do (using `array_shift` instead of `array_pop`):

```
$split = explode(" ", $request->name);

$firstname = array_shift($split);
$lastname  = implode(" ", $split);
```

Works with both a single name, multiple names and an empty string. No conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

here's what i like to do:

```
$firstname = explode(' ', trim($fullname))[0];
```

or with laravel helper **head**:

```
$firstname = head(explode(' ', trim($fullname)));
```

or if you are positive that fullname is not empty:

```
$firstname = strtok(trim($fullname),  ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it looks not bad :)

```
list($firstName, $lastName) = array_pad(explode(' ', trim($fullName)), 2, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following.

```
$list = list($firstName, $lastName) = array_pad(explode(' ', 
    trim($name)), 2, null);

print_r([
    'firstname' => trim(str_replace($list[(count($list)-1)],"",$name)),
    'lastname' => $list[(count($list)-1)]
]);
```